# Can XCode5 automatically build fat (device+simulator) libs?

Tags: xcode, xcode5, x86-64

I noticed in XCode5, when building I now sometimes see "creating universal binary" as a status near the end of the build. I think this is to do with i386/x86_64 but wondered, does this mean I can now also build a combined simulator and device lib in a single pass, rather than having to use lipo as a post-build step?